# Record the timestamp when Broken Pipe occurs?

Tags: ssh, openssh, timestamp

When something goes wrong, SSH prints a message like the following:

```
$ ...
$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 45.78.157.165: Broken pipe
```

I'd like to get a timestamp with the error to help with trends and torubleshooting. For example:

```
$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 45.78.157.165: Broken pipe at 2016/03/03 09:00:00
```

How do I tell SSH client to write the time when the problem occured?

Answer (score 0):

Running the command somehow like

```
ssh yourhost || date
```

should do what you need.

You can simply test with writing <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> into the ssh session, which will terminate the connection for you (end `ssh` with non-zero return code).